# Python unittesting how to test while having db_session.query on my function?

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest

I am new to python and i'm trying unit test over my python project for a function

```
def getFundPosition(self, enterprise_id=None, since=None, till=datetime.datetime.today()):
    """

    :param enterprise_id:
    :param since:
    :param till:
    :return:
    """
bank = self.db_session.query(AccountGroup).filter(
        AccountGroup.enterprise_id == enterprise_id, AccountGroup.name == AccountGroup.BANK_GROUP_NAME).first()
    cash = self.db_session.query(AccountGroup).filter(
        AccountGroup.enterprise_id == enterprise_id, AccountGroup.name == AccountGroup.CASH_GROUP_NAME).first()
    fund = float(
        bank.getBalance(since, till, approved_only=True) + cash.getBalance(since, till, approved_only=True))
```

on the other hand testing code like to be below

```
class AccountsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #every test needs a client
    def test_dashboard(self):
        response = AccountsDAO().getFundPosition(121,'2016-01-01','2017-12-01')
```

It throws error as below

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getBalance'
```

I want to know is that im doing is correct way to test or it will not execute self.db_session.query under unit testing case scenario

Pls help me on this

Comment: There are several problems with this example. One thing is the signature `till` should not have a hard coded datetime default value. Inject the datetime, you can't test it otherwise. Also you're failing because your query is returning `None` for cash and you don't check for that.

Comment: thanks @Dan I will fix this..